# Build a matrix from vectors in Fortran95

Tags: arrays, matrix, vector, fortran, fortran95

By using the following code, I am trying to build a 3*3 matrix, but unable to do so. Any help will be appreciated.

```
program array

  implicit none
  integer i, a(5), b(5), a1(5), a2(5), a3(5)
  integer, dimension (5,5) :: mat1

  a = [0,1,2,3,4]
  b = [1,2,2,2,1]

  i = 0
  do i = 1,5
    a1(i) = a(i)*a(i)
    a2(i) = a(i)
    a3(i) = 1
    print*, a1(i), a2(i), a3(i)
  end do

  do i=1,5
    mat1(i,:) = [a1(:,i),a2(:,i),a3(:,i)]
    print*, mat1
  end do

end program array
```

In my output, I am expecting to have a 5*3 matrix having as [a1; a2; a3]. But, I am getting the following errors.

```
$ gfortran -Wall -c "HW1.f95" #(in directory: Y:\Fortran & subroutines)

HW1.f95:28.20:
mat1(:,i) = [a1(:,i);a2(:,i);a3(:,i)]
                1
Error: Syntax error in array constructor at (1)
HW1.f95:28.26:
mat1(:,i) = [a1(:,i);a2(:,i);a3(:,i)]
                      1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
HW1.f95:28.34:
mat1(:,i) = [a1(:,i);a2(:,i);a3(:,i)]
                              1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Do you mean "5*5", given your declarations, etc.  Further, why do you think you aren't getting such a matrix?  Just because of the way the output is presented?  Is there a compiler error?  Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I mean 5*5. Compiler throws errors for the last loop.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to get "a1" as the first column vector. "a2" second and "a3" third. It will be a 5*3 matrix. Output matrix will look like [a1; a2; a3]. I am getting the following errors. 
 gfortran -Wall -c "HW1.f95" (in directory: Y:\Fortran & subroutines)
HW1.f95:28.20:
mat1(:,i) = [a1(:,i);a2(:,i);a3(:,i)]
                    1
Error: Syntax error in array constructor at (1)
HW1.f95:28.26:
mat1(:,i) = [a1(:,i);a2(:,i);a3(:,i)]
                          1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
HW1.f95:28.34:
mat1(:,i) = [a1(:,i);a2(:,i);a3(:,i)]
 
Compilation failed.

Comment: Thanks I have edit the original question.

Comment: I have fixed the error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It turns out compilers are better at debugging code than I am.  In `[a1(:,i),a2(:,i),a3(:,i)]` you are referencing `a1` as a rank-2 array, not the rank-1 it is.  And the same for the others.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: you are also only assigning 3 items to a length 5 row.

Comment: You could also have declared a and b like " a=[0,1,2,3,4] " like you did later for a more compact form.  It's a nice feature.

Answer (score 1):

Put the three length-5 arrays (a2,a2,a3) into a single length-15 array and use RESHAPE:

```
program fill_mat1
    integer, dimension(5,3) :: mat1
    integer, dimension(5)   :: a1,a2,a3
    integer, dimension(15)  :: a123

    a1 = (/  1, 2, 3, 4, 5 /)
    a2 = (/  6, 7, 8, 9,10 /)
    a3 = (/ 11,12,13,14,15 /)
    a123(1:5)   = a1
    a123(6:10)  = a2
    a123(11:15) = a3
    mat1 = RESHAPE(a123,mat1)
end program
```

RESHAPE takes the values from a123 and fills them into the shape of mat1 in Fortran standard order. There are also options for ordering the values, and for padding when the number of elements between the list and the shape do not agree. This is all covered in documentation of the RESHAPE intrinsic.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for the compilation to fail in your program

- You said you are

  > expecting to have a 5*3 matrix

  For that you need to either declare `mat1` to be a 5*3 matrix in your declaration like

  ```
  integer, dimension (5,3) :: mat1
  ```

  or by only writing on the first three entries later on, like

  ```
  do i=1,5
    mat1(i,1:3) = [a1(i),a2(i),a3(i)]
    print*, mat1
  end do
  ```

  Thes second opiton would still leave you with a 5*5 matrix but it would only be filled in the first tree columns.
- You declared `a1`,`a2` and `a3` to be one dimensional. As @francescalus already pointed out in the comments you are trying to access there arrays like they have two dimensions, which doesn't work. This is a possibility

  ```
  mat1(i,1:3) = [a1(i),a2(i),a3(i)]
  ```